# Jquery use passed arguments inside a html filled variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched related to this issue of mine,couldn't find the answer, so here i am asking which may be a silly question.

Here is my code.

```
function addCategory(data_type,header){
categoryDialog = $("<div id='parentcategoryDiv'>" +
    '*header* Name<input type="text" id="categoryText" name="categoryText" style="width: 300px;" placeholder="Program Type"/>' +
    '<br/>' +
    '<br/>' +
    '<input type="submit" name="saveCategory" value="Save" id="saveCategory" class="right" onclick="saveCategory(*data_type*);">' +
    '<input type="submit" name="cancelCategory" value="Cancel" id="cancelCategory" class="right" onclick="closeDialog();">' +
    "</div>");

categoryDialog.dialog({
    title: 'Add/Edit '+header,
    maxWidth:500,
    maxHeight: 100,
    width: 500,
    height: 100,
    draggable: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
});
categoryDialog.dialog('open');
$("body").on("click", ".ui-widget-overlay", function () {
    closeDialog();
});
```

};

The header and data_type are two passed arguments. But the problem is I am unable to use these arguments(header and data_type) inside the html filled variables. Is there a way ? Any help is appreciated .

Comment: In the first part, you are just outputting the _literal_ value `data_type`, as part of a text literal/string. You need to concatenate the static parts and the variable, like you did in the second part with the value for `title`. (And depending on what data type `data_type` actually is, you might need quotes around the function parameter as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the issue of string concatenation while passing the parameter to the onclick function. Try this, i have used a escape character to reserve single quotation so that the passed parameter will be passed as string for the onclick method; Try this and let me know if it worked or not!

```
function addCategory(data_type,header){
categoryDialog = $("<div id='parentcategoryDiv'>" +
''+header+' Name<input type="text" id="categoryText" name="categoryText" style="width: 300px;" placeholder="Program Type"/>' +
'<br/>' +
'<br/>' +
'<input type="submit" name="saveCategory" value="Save" id="saveCategory" class="right" onclick="saveCategory(\''+data_type+'\');">' +
'<input type="submit" name="cancelCategory" value="Cancel" id="cancelCategory" class="right" onclick="closeDialog();">' +
"</div>");

console.log(categoryDialog);

categoryDialog.dialog({
title: 'Add/Edit '+header,
maxWidth:500,
maxHeight: 100,
width: 500,
height: 100,
draggable: true,
autoOpen: false,
modal: true
});
categoryDialog.dialog('open');
$("body").on("click", ".ui-widget-overlay", function () {
closeDialog();
});
};
```